# How to get css selector of clicked-on element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to javascript and css and I'm trying to develop a chrome extension which when the user clicks on an element of a specific class in the webpage, it automatically clicks also the next 5 elements.

I found that the css selectors of all the elements of that class are identical up to a number, so I tried the following:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    document.querySelector(
        '#selector_first_part... > div:nth-child('+
        i +
        ') > selector_second_part).click();
}
```

The code above works fine when I manually set i.

The problem is that I need to extract "i" from the clicked-on element, and in order to do that I thought that I need to get the css selector of the clicked-on element.
I tried to inject a script to the source code that adds an eventListener to each element of that class, which sends the ID of the clicked-on element, and using the ID i thought that I could extract the css selector. here is the code:

```
var actualCode = `

     var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('someClass');

    var onClickFunction = function() {
        var id = this.getAttribute('id');
        alert("This object's ID is " + id);
    };

    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].addEventListener('click', onClickFunction, false);
    }   

`;

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = actualCode;
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.remove();
```

When running this code the alert says "This object's ID is null", meaning that I can't get the css selector using the ID, because it seems that the elements have no ID.

So my question is: how could I click (with JS) the surrounding elements of the clicked-on element?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st of all, placing your code into a DOM load event like @eytienne already mentioned is used to make sure the page is loaded before attaching your event.
2nd: you should not need to attach several handler, just one click handler on document- then use the target to get the actual element that was clicked, e.g.

```
const handler = function(e) {
  const elem = e.target;
}
document.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
```

3rd: you don't need an id, just compare all elements, e.g. (in your handler):

```
const target = e.target;
for (let i=0,elems=document.querySelectorAll(..);i<elems.length;i++) {
if(elems[i] === target) {
 ... do something ...
}
```

I did not test the code.. just to give you an idea.
I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace your script manipulation with that:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    // put your actualCode here
});
```

Look at this ressource in detail (on Mozilla Developper Network, the official documentation):

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

---

I think you did not understand the purpose of an 'id' in the HTML context so discover it (MDN is always a good resource ;) ):

https://www.google.com/search?q=id+mdn

Comment: *https://www.google.com/search?q=id+mdn* searching on Google is very easy and it gives multiple results so it is hard to find what you are exactly telling about. try to provide main content by links like [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp)